# For given Joint pdf, Find the value of $c$

Tags: random-variables, density-function, marginal-distribution

**My Working:**

So I have been practicing for my upcoming exam. This is from one of my past exam papers, and I am unable to solve it. The thing that confuses me is that the given pdf $f_X,_Y(x,k)$ involves $k$ and I am supposed to find value of $c$ in part $a$ which is not possible until $k$ is not known to me. Once I have $k$ it is pretty easy to find $c$ by integrating over the given domain equating it to $1$ and then solve for $c$. I have tried but calculations becomes messy and unreasonable that I feel stuck. Am I supposed to integrate given pdf w.r.t $dx$ $dk$ and $k$ is just assumed to be there? I don't know. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In standard probabilistic terminology $X,Y$ does not have a pdf, so the questions is meaningless.

Comment: But the questions says it is.

Comment: @Ameer786 :You are given the following

$$f_{XY}(x,l)=12(l+1)(1-x)^3x^{c+l+1}$$

First sum w.r.t. $l \in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ obtaining

$$12x^{c+1}(1-x)^3\underbrace{\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(l+1)x^l}_{(1-x)^{-2}}=12x^{c+1}(1-x)$$

Then integrate in dx, always using the known result you can use given in the exercise

$$\int_0^112x^{c+1}(1-x)dx=1$$

finding $c$

Comment: @Ameer786 :to solve the integral without their hint use a [Beta Function][1] thus

$$12\int_0^1x^{c+1}(1-x)dx=12\int_0^1x^{(c+2)-1}(1-x)^{2-1}dx=12\frac{\Gamma(c+2)\cdot\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(c+2+2)}=$$

$$=12\frac{(c+1)!}{(c+3)!}=\frac{12}{(c+3)(c+2)}=1$$

that is evidently $c=1$ without other calculations


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: @tommik Thanks. I got everything. I think I can do rest from here. Thanks alot